# Facebook request does not redirect to my android app

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am currently developing an android game using facebook invites (such as ruzzle or draw sthg). I have successfully passed the login part and the request part. However, whenever I make a request to a friend to invite him to play with me and they receive the request on the facebook app for android when they click on the request, the phone opens up the google play store. I do not understand why because the app is already installed on the phone and so it should open up the app directly right?

I used the exact same code as shown in the facebook developers site and I configured my app on their developers site too.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you turned on deep linking in your app settings on the developers site?

Comment: yes I tried with both deep linking enabled and disabled

Comment: No one had this problem before?